# Postfix "SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found"

Tags: debian, postfix, authentication, sasl

Trying to use postfix with smtp to connect to google's smtp.  When trying to send mail, I get this error:

```
Sep 15 14:04:41 zedsaid postfix/smtp[20271]: certificate verification failed for smtp.gmail.com[74.125.95.109]:587: untrusted issuer /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
Sep 15 14:04:42 zedsaid postfix/smtp[20271]: warning: SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found
Sep 15 14:04:42 zedsaid postfix/smtp[20271]: 1BACD968B23: to=<nic@zedsaid.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[74.125.95.109]:587, delay=0.92, delays=0.06/0.03/0.83/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.gmail.com[74.125.95.109]: no mechanism available)
```

Running Debian 4.0.

Ideas?

Comment: Post the output of `postconf -n` and all other relevant configuration files of Postfix. You don't seem to have `smtp_sasl_password_maps` configured in your `main.cf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the clue is right here:

```
untrusted issuer /C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
```

you need to get the equifax cert and add it to your list of trusted CA certs.

I think that these are available here: http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/

Answer (score 9):

I have the error: `SASL authentication failure: No worthy mechs found`

with postfix running in a RaspberryPi3 (Debian 10 - Raspbian)

I fix installing the package `libsasl2-modules`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libsasl2-modules
```

Hope it can help someone else.

Comment: This fixed it for me on Raspbian. Thank you.

Comment: Same here, thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

(New user, can't post comment reply to sebix. Also removed all links.)

For modern installations (such as Ubuntu 16.04) that use Postfix as an SMTP client with SASL-auth to a remote server (e.g. like shown on the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PostfixAndSASL#SASL_authentication_in_the_Postfix_SMTP_client)), it might indeed be needed to specify

```
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

What this does, however, is remove the `noplaintext` option (currently the default is `noplaintext, noanonymous` as per the postconf manual). `smtp_sasl_tls_security_options` defaults to `$smtp_sasl_security_options`. This could become an issue under some (mis)configurations, or in the future if defaults change.

EDITED: At the moment, though, it doesn't seem likely, especially if SASL is done in a TLS session. This is forced if the remote server has `smtpd_tls_auth_only` or `smtpd_enforce_tls` (which implies the former) or whatever non-Postfix equivalent.

To check what Postfix defaults to, use `postconf -d` ([via](https://serverfault.com/a/329297/384812)).

Comment: Thanks!  Worked for me on new Debian 11 Proxmox container.

Answer (score 4):

## this solved it for me (on centos 7 not default, was OK on older Centos versions)

```
yum install cyrus-sasl{,-plain} 
service postfix restart
```

Comment: This solved it for me using Alpine. Although Alpine doesn't list a cyrus-sasl-plain package I was able to install it and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly multiple problems here, the certs being one and another maybe related to `smtp_sasl_security_options`. I once solved a problem involving that "no mechs" message by setting `smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous` following a clue found on linuxquestions.org

Comment: What is the suggested solution?